# Getting duplicate elements in react component after fetchMore

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I want to `fetchMore` data when `onscroll` reaches the bottom. The issue I have is that I get duplicate elements thus console yelling at me as well that I nee `unique element keys`. I'm getting the correct data in the graphql playground so it's an issue in my `react` component. Does this logic make sense? What's going wrong here?

```
class App extends Component {
  isBottom = (fetchMore, data) => {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      if (
        data &&
        data.infiniteScrollMovies &&
        data.infiniteScrollMovies.hasMore &&
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      ) {
        console.log('YES!')
        this.fetchMoreData(fetchMore, data)
      }
    }
  }

  fetchMoreData = (fetchMore, data) => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        offset: data.infiniteScrollMovies.newOffset,
      },
      updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev

        return {
          ...fetchMoreResult,
          infiniteScrollMovies: {
            ...fetchMoreResult.infiniteScrollMovies,
            movies: [...prev.infiniteScrollMovies.movies, ...fetchMoreResult.infiniteScrollMovies.movies],
          },
        }
      },
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-column">
        <Query query={ALL_MOVIES} notifyOnNetworkStatusChange={true} fetchPolicy="network-only">
          {({ data, loading, error, fetchMore }) => {
            if (error) return <h1>{error.message}</h1>
            this.isBottom(fetchMore, data)
            return (
              <div>
                {data &&
                  data.infiniteScrollMovies &&
                  data.infiniteScrollMovies.movies.map(m => (
                    <article key={m.id}>
                    // ... rendering an element
                    </article>
                  ))}
           <div>{loading && <h1 className="red text-center">Loading...</h1>}</div>
```

Here's my query:

```
export const ALL_MOVIES = gql`
  query infiniteScrollMovies($offset: Int) {
    infiniteScrollMovies(offset: $offset, limit: 16) {
      movies {
        image_url
        title
        id
      }
      hasMore
      newOffset
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `variables` parameter in `updataeQuery` to handle this scenario, basically you need to prevent the appending in cache if already its done.

Change your updateQuery to below

```
        updateQuery: (prev, { variables, fetchMoreResult }) => {
// Return the prev values, if it allready has the length specified by offset
// thereby preventing duplicate values in cache.
                        if (!fetchMoreResult || 
                           prev.infiniteScrollMovies.movies.length > variables.offset) 
                         return prev
```

Answer (score 1):

try disable the notifyOnNetworkStatusChange option

Comment: This solved my problem where useQuery requests using networkPolicy: cache-first were not refetching when component re-rendered with different variables. Thanks!